# Encountering an exception during context initialization while attempting to start hybrisserver in debug mode

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have recently setup Hybris 2005 in my machine. The server was running fine till yesterday, but on attempting to restart this morning I'm getting an exception and my wrapper is stopped. There were absolutely no changes made, I had attempted to start the server in debug mode. Kindly assist me in getting rid of the issue, I'm new to Hybris and can't find any cause for this issue. Here's relevant the log for hybrisserver.bat debug:

```
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:40.573 | INFO  [localhost-startStop-5] (junit) [LazyInitOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor] Setting lazy-init='false' for configuration beans
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.425 | WARN  [localhost-startStop-5] (junit) [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listMergeBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [core-spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 | ERROR [localhost-startStop-5] (junit) [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listMergeBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [core-spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$156/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.533 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:48.534 |     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:52.153 | Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:52.261 | INFO  [localhost-startStop-2] (junit) [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (55.50 μs)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:52.261 | de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException: Error creating Spring application context.
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.901 | WARN  [Thread-6] (junit) [AbstractTenant] Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'listMergeBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [core-spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.901 | org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'listMergeBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [core-spring.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:307) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:179) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:165) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:122) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:101) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1116) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:65) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:279) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheAdapter.java:512) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.902 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1150) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1014) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.MasterTenant.shutDown(MasterTenant.java:217) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1002) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:67) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.internalRun(RedeployUtilities.java:32) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:53.903 | at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:54.998 | INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry] AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted - stopping now: null
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:54.998 | INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry] AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted/terminated but without InterruptedException - stopping now.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.757 | ERROR [Thread-6] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region entityCacheRegion. Last key LegacyCacheKey(master)[key=[hjmp, entity, 87, 8797249405015], valueType=NON_SERIALIZABLE, typeCode=87{LegacyCacheKeyType[hjmp, entity, 87(String)]}} class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.key.legacy.LegacyCacheKey
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.759 | ERROR [Thread-6] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region entityCacheRegion. Last key null null
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | WARN  [Thread-6] [AbstractTenant] The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:2066) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getAllKeys(EHCacheRegion.java:423) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:283) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheAdapter.java:512) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1150) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1014) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.760 | at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.761 | at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:67) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.761 | at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.internalRun(RedeployUtilities.java:32) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:55.761 | at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:56.314 | INFO  [Thread-6] [DefaultClusterNodeManagementService] Unregistering assigned cluster node id 0...
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2021/07/30 10:21:57.311 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Please help.

Comment: please remove junit tenant .
add properties in local.properties
#remove extra tenants
installed.tenants=
then try to restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an issue about your Java memory.

You have to check JVM parameters in local.properties.

Probably you need to change the Xss value using `-Xss1024k`

Comment: Yes, this is most likely the issue since the server fails to start when I'm running a lot of resource intensive background programs which utilize JDK simultaneously. I have tried running the server with fewer dependencies and lesser background resources and haven't encountered this issue since. Thank you for pointing that out.